# Need to first ssh and ping using ansible-playbook

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, redhat, ping

Suppose I have 100 hosts and I want to perform a ssh connection where the  result should print "YES" or "NO"

Then perform a ping that should print  "YES" or "NO"

1. if ssh make then print Y other No
2. if ssh make Y then try to perform Ping and print Y along with uptime
3. if ping getting not access then print N

For example

```
SL.No. Server       Ping SSH     Uptime(hrs)           
1      Linux-test     y   y      2020-26-05 17:17:44  
2      linux-test1    n   -      -                      
3      linux-test3    y   y      2020-26-05 17:17:44
```

Comment: Once you connect the server with SSH, then why you need to ping again? Only if port 22 is opened on destination server you can ssh and ping...

Comment: And so what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? You may want to read [ask]

Comment: – Pradeep Kumar  firstly i need to check ping if ping getting successfully  then try to SSH along with Uptime then exit

Comment: if ping not successful then print status No and ssh is no or - same for uptime

Answer (score 0):

here is a possible way to achieve it.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  ignore_errors: True
  ignore_unreachable: True
  tasks:
  - name: ping server
    ping:
    register: ping_status

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} - YES"
    with_items:
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    when: ping_status.ping is defined

  - name: get uptime
    shell: uptime > /root/uptime.out

  - name: read uptime
    command: cat /root/uptime.out
    register: uptime_server

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} - YES - {{ uptime_server.stdout }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    when: ping_status.ping is defined

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} - NO"
    with_items:
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    when: ping_status.ping is undefined
```